# Add different column values based on conditional values of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following output from a SQL query:

```
Project_Manager_ID   PROject_Rank  On_boarding_Gap    Project_Gap    End_Gap
101                   1                   2                 3           0.833
101                   2                   7                 1           3.4
101                   3                   0                 -3           0
101                   4                   3                 1            1.2
102                   1                   -1                 0            1
102                   2                    2                 3            2
102                   3                    5                 2           -3
```

This is the business rule:

When Rank =1 then On_boarding_gap

when Rank >1 and Rank < (max(rank) group by Project_Manager_ID) then Project_gap

When Rank = max(rank) group by Project_Manager_ID then End_Gap

Add all those different gaps and find the total value of Gaps for each Project_Manager_ID. Ignore all negative values.
Therefore in the above example for **Project_Manager_ID =101**

On_boarding_gap =2

Project_gap = 1 & -3 = 1 (ignoring -3 value)

End_Gap = 1.2

the total Gaps is (2+1 +1.2) = 4.2.

**for Project_Manager_ID =102**

On_boarding_gap =-1 = 0 (ignoring -1 value)

Project_gap = 3

End_Gap = -3 = 0 (ignoring -3 value)

the total Gaps is ( 0+ 3+0) = 3

I am not sure how to write a query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . a `case` expression and window functions gets you the gaps for each row:

```
select t.*,
       (case when project_rank = 1
             then on_boarding_gap
             when project_rank < max(project_rank) over (partition by Project_Manager_ID)
             then Project_gap
             else End_Gap
        end) as imputed_gap
from t;
```

Then aggregation:

```
select Project_Manager_ID, sum(imputed_gap)
from (select t.*,
             (case when project_rank = 1
                   then on_boarding_gap
                   when project_rank < max(project_rank) over (partition by Project_Manager_ID)
                   then Project_gap
                   else End_Gap
              end) as imputed_gap
      from t
     ) t
where imputed_gap >= 0
group by Project_Manager_ID
```